# Code ignighter .htaccess

Tags: php, codeigniter, .htaccess

I'm writing a site using code ignighter. Here is my current .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|js|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ci/index.php/$1 [L]
```

I have a user controller that that among other things, displays a profile when accessed from the url like so

mysite.com/user/getProfile/$username

What I'd like to do is get rid of the getProfile so that mysitecom/user/$username will call the get profile function. While still keeping the code above. If I have to sacrifice being able to have other functions in that controller so be it.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: In routes.php file add following:
$route['user/(:any)'] = 'user/getProfile/$1';

Comment: I agree with Ula, routes.php should be utilized to handle routing requests in CI, not the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

In your "User" Controller do not pass the $username in the getProfile() function.

What you would do is... you pass the $username in you default function.

Let say for example, you have this index function who is the default landing page is index().

and in your router you have this configuration

```
$route['default_controller'] = "user/index";
$route['(:any)'] = 'user/index/$1';
```

And in your controller class, this should look like this...

```
class User extends CI_Controller {

    public function index($page = 'user') 
    {
        if ($this->uri->segment(2) != '') {
           $data['Profile'] = $this->_getProfile($this->uri->segment(2));
        }

        $this->load->view($page, $data);
    }

    private _getProfile($usernanme)
    {
        // This will return the profile of the user
    }

}
```

Hope that is clear enough... :)

Answer (score 0):

Here are examples of CI Url Rewrite

First .htaccess to get rid of index.php

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Then in config.php edit

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Then just simple example of controller and routes.php in config folder

```
$route['default_controller'] = "main";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route["contact"] = 'main/contact';
$route["(.*)"] = 'main/tekstovi/$1';
```

And example of controller

```
class Main extends CI_Controller {


    public function index()
    {
        $this->home();
    }

    public function home()
    {


        $this->load->view("view_home", $data);

    }


    public function tekstovi()
        {

        $data['results'] = $this->get_db->('TABELNAME',$this->uri->segment(1));
        $this->load->view("view_tekstovi", $data);

    }
    public function contact()
        {

        $this->load->view("view_contact", $data);

    }


}
```

You can add .html at the end of url just editing config.php

```
$config['url_suffix'] = '.html';
```

This is just simple example, try to add your own :)